# update .text() using ajax auto refresh

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

When I set the session in a file called `signin.php`:

```
$user = 'john';
$_SESSION['user'] = $user;

echo "
<script>
$.ajax({
    url: 'array.php', 
    type: 'post',
    data: {'user': $user}
});
";
```

In another file (`index.php`), I want to get:

```
<?php

session_start();

echo "log in as <span id=\"user\"></span><br/>"; 
$user =  $_POST['user']

echo "
<script>
$('#user').text(function() {
    setInterval(function(){
        $('#user').load($user).fadeIn(10);
    }, 1000);
</script>
";

?>
```

I know I completely messed up with the code. What I want is that when the session is set in the `signin.php` file, I want `$user` in the content in "log in as `$user`" automatically updated without refresh the page, any help will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I think $('#span') should be $("#user")...

Comment: signin can do a ajax post and get a json results back that contains name, you would then set the variable to the value sent through json and then display on your page, not really sure why you have php echo out a bunch of javascript, i dont code php but apparently you can output json http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php  json is then easy to absorb within jquery

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, work on diligently formatting your code more effectively. That code you posted was all over the place. This is a bad practice to get in and leads to errors, bugs, and other effects which can be difficult find due to the formatting.

If I follow what you're doing, when someone logs in and then hits the `index.php` page, you want to be able to load a user's information from another file that will give back the user data asynchronously?

**signin.php**

Your code is confusing in what it appears to be doing; you simply have not told us enough both in code and explanation to understand what the workflow entails.

For instance, in `signin.php`, you're `echo`ing a `<script>` tag that does an `$.ajax()` request, but who/what get's this code? Is this part of the `signin.php` content, if the user successfully logs in? Does this mean the `signin.php` will load the *page* to use the `$.ajax()` here, or is that meant to run *from* the `$.ajax()` on `success`?

If it's the latter, you need to return regular Javascript with no markup (like a `<script>` tag wrapped around it) and use `dataType: 'script'` in the options.

Also, I would at least use a more descriptive word than `array.php`; if you're getting user data from it, name that file something like `userdata.php`.

```
$user = 'john';
$_SESSION['user'] = $user;

echo "
<script>
$.ajax({
    url: 'userdata.php', 
    type: 'post',
    dataType: 'script',
    data: 'json=' + jQuery.serialize({user: '$user'})
});
";
```

Then in `userdata.php`, you can access it with `$_POST['json']`.

**index.php**

This honestly makes no sense:

```
$('#user').text(function() {
    setInterval(function(){
        $('#user').load($user).fadeIn(10);
    }, 1000);
);
```

Why is the `setInterval()` in an anonymous function that's run while setting `$.text()`? This is one of those *What?* moments, where I'm not even sure what you're trying to accomplish.

Before that though, you have:

```
$user = $_POST['user'] <<< Note here, you need a ; at the end
```

Why is this a `$_POST`? Does the `signin.php` use `$_POST` to log a user in? Here, I believe you want `$_SESSION` (I think, hope, ??), since that's where you stored the username when the user logged in using `signin.php`.

This is my best guess as to what you're trying to do (assuming you're returning JSON-formatted data):

```
<?php

session_start();

$user =  $_SESSION['user'];

echo "log in as <span id=\"user\"></span><br/>"; 

echo "
<script>
$.ajax({
    url: 'userdata.php',
    type: 'post',
    data: 'json=' + jQuery.serialize({user:'$user'}),
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(data){
        $('#user').text(data.fullname);
    }
});
</script>
";

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
<?php
    $user = 'john';
    $_SESSION['user'] = $user;
?>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $.ajax({
        url: 'array.php', 
        type: 'post',
        data: { 'user': <? echo json_encode($user) ?> }
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Note the `setInterval()`s use. This seems to deal with the first part, when I think the second part is where the problem is.